# Lazyvim Update Pop-up

Tags: neovim

I am new to the vim configurations, so I have installed Lazyvim (on Neovim). I have the default configuration and was wondering how I can get rid of this Update-Pop-Up. It pops up everytime and I always have to wait a few seconds before I can get started.

[image: Here is the pop up]

Thanks in advance

I haven't found any help online

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Overriding the default behavior of the lazy.nvim package manager plugin within the LazyVim framework is simple, but it's not the same as if you were editing configurations of non-core plugins that are loaded when LazyVim is initializing.

To disable the update notification, edit the file `nvim/lua/config/lazy.lua` and modify the `checker` field within the setup function for lazy, and disable the `notify` field:

```lua
require("lazy").setup({
  checker = { enabled = true, notify = false }, -- automatically check for plugin updates
})
```

Also, it might be useful to know the keymapping `<leader>un`, which also closes any active notifications.

Happy (neo)vimming!